# Apple Style Scrolling Animation

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, vertical-scrolling

Im trying to achieve an apple like scrolling animation for a project I'm doing, I've made the scroll on a fixed canvas using JS and CSS but I want the canvas to scroll off the screen once its finished animating. Anyone able to offer any advice...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
    <canvas id="hero-lightpass" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
      
    
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  background: #fff;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 200vw;
  max-height: 200vh;
}
```

**
JS**

```
/*eslint-env es6*/
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 63;
const currentFrame = index => (
 `https://antiviral-semaphore.000webhostapp.com/TestExport/JPG/Test${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width=2230;
canvas.height=559;
img.onload=function(){
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
```

Example of my project can be found https://antiviral-semaphore.000webhostapp.com/Test.html

Thanks Neil

I have tried adjusting the canvas position setting and anything other than fixed makes it scroll up but only fixed will let it animate.